# How to extract the content between 2 sibling nodes in an XML document using Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

sample xml document:

```
<a>
    <b>...</b>
    xyz
    <c>...</c>
</a>
```

Is there a way to extract the content `xyz` placed between the tags `b` and `c` using Java code (through DOM parsing)?

Comment: Is this the fixed fomat?

Comment: Please, formulate a correct question. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that element refers to tag 'a' following code should extract what you want and work also if you have content before and after the 'b' and 'c' tags

```
    NodeList content = element.getChildNodes();
    StringBuilder textContent = new StringBuilder();
    int cntLength = content.getLength();
    for ( int i = 0; i < cntLength; i++ ) {
        Node paramValue = content.item( i );
        short type = paramValue.getNodeType();
        if ( ( type == Node.TEXT_NODE ) || ( type == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE ) ) {
            textContent.append( ((CharacterData) paramValue).getData() );   //  Both Text and CDATASection nodes are SubType of CharacterData
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the nodes of root element (`<a>`). In your example the second node (with index 2, since nodes are indexed from 1) will be the text node.

```
Document document = ...; // create org.w3c.dom.Document instance from XML
document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(2).getTextContent();
```